# 0xc0000225 error after cloning windows 7 from one disk to another using dd

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, dd, disk-cloning

We have two hard disks. One is 80GB, most likely damaged/corrupt/failing. The second is 320GB. In the 80GB disk, we have Windows 7 enterprise installed. Since we would like to keep our application configurations, we first attempted to repair the 80GB (Startup repair, system restore, chkdsk, last good known configuration) with no success. Windows 7 flag shows at bootup and then it reboots.

We then decided to clone the content of the disk to another disk. The 80GB drive has two partitions. One 100MB, system reserved, and one 78GB. We created in gparted 2 partitions on the 320GB disk, one 100MB and the second 78GB. We then tried to `dd` each partition of the first drive to the second:

```
dd /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
dd /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
```

Both of those attempts failed immediately because dd complained about `I/O error`.

We then found we can ignore errors, so we ran:

```
dd /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 conv=sync,noerror
dd /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 conv=sync,noerror
```

Those commands worked. The second command which was for the 78GB partition took many hours and there were many ignored errors. Nevertheless, we mounted the new 78GB partition and everything was there. All the folders of Windows 7 in place, and we could view file content without problem from within our Linux environment. However when we tried to boot from the new hard drive, Windows Boot Manager threw this error on bootup:

```
Windows failed to start (and more text like this)
Status: 0xc0000225
Info: A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed
```

We tried startup repair on this new drive. Startup repair said it found problems with startup and fixed them. But when we tried booting again, same error. We attempted startup repair one more time with the same result though.

Did we do the cloning the wrong way? Or is it because the first disk had issues? Maybe we have to do another step to make the new disk bootable?

Comment: I think you are better off using a tool like clonezilla and clone the entire disk.  This would eliminate a number of variables.

Comment: The original disk might be completely corrupted now, we can't even mount partitions

Comment: The correct way would have been to create a complete image of the defect hdd disk and then use (forensic) tools to extract the data you need. Manual cloning a defect drive and then try to boot it was a very bad idea.

Comment: If you clone a damaged disk, then you get a new disk with corrupt data..

Comment: @Robert How do you create a complete image of the defect disk?

Comment: If clone will not work then making a disk image will be corrupt also, they are essentially the same process. Send the drive to a recovery expert or start over and reinstall the OS and programs.

Comment: Try a repair by booting off of a W7 install disc or usb.  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next." 
 3. Click "Repair your computer."

Comment: @Tasos Of course you have to clone the disk before it is finally not working anymore. From your description this was the case as you first started. For imaging defect drives special tools like `dd_rescue` are available.

Comment: @Moab we tried that no success